# How to focus an HTML checkbox in IE, causing it to gain highlight

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble programmatically causing an HTML checkbox object to become highlighted after gaining focus. Here is a simple example of the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doIt(){
        document.getElementById("theCheckbox").focus();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onClick="doIt()" value="Push Me">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="theCheckbox">
```

Clicking the "Push Me" button causes the checkbox to gain focus. I know this because the checkbox becomes checked if you hit the spacebar after clicking the button. However, at no point is the checkbox highlighted. The type of highlighting I'm talking about appears to work in IE naturally under the following circumstances...

Press the Tab key until the "Push Me" button is outlined in a dotted line. Now click the "Push Me" button again. The checkbox should be outlined in the dotted line I'm trying to programmatically create (without having to mess around by hitting the Tab key first).

Image of the desired effect that I can only seem to achieve after messing with the Tab key:

[image: highlighted checkbox image]

This was all done in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to duplicate this error and I was able to, but I also noticed something else.

If I first tab-selected *any* element on the page (i.e., not necessarily the checkbox) and *then* clicked the button, the focus highlight worked as expected.

This really makes me believe that this is a browser issue you probably can't get around.

Comment: Which brings up the question, any way I can simulate the tab select action in IE7?

Answer (score 1):

What you might be seeing are different browser implementations of how a checkbox is highlighted when it has focus.

Which particular browser were you referring to?

In **FireFox**, a highlighted checkbox has a slight orange border with a very faint dashed line.

**IE6** seems to give no indication when a checkbox has focus, only when you hover over it do you get a visual cue that it is checkable (slight orange border).

Comment: Everything done above was IE7, which supports some form of checkbox outline (as shown in the SS). I'll have to double-check which IE we're supposed to be officially supporting. If it's IE6, maybe this isn't even something I need to be worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE7 but try this... (works in IE6 running with Wine)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doIt(){
        document.getElementById("theButton").blur();
        document.getElementById("theCheckbox").focus();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="theButton" onClick="doIt()" value="Push Me">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="theCheckbox">
```

Comment: @Pedro - must be the wine, calling blur on theButton before focus still yields no focus visual cue in IE 6

Comment: look at this screenshot: http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/9458/pantallazo1m.png

Comment: @Pedro- did you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at all during your test?

Comment: As it looks like you guys have already found, this only works when pressing tab to instantiate (for lack of a better term) the dotted focus outline